# How to make a unique id inside while loop?

Tags: javascript, php

first of all im noob when it comes to coding so please be gentle.
I have a php while loop and inside the loop I have a form with input type of text with an Id, how can I make the id unique or ++?

```
    $list = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $pro_id = $row['product_id'];
        $pro_cat = $row['product_cat'];
        $pro_makat = $row['product_makat'];
        $pro_title = $row['product_title'];
        $pro_price = $row['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row['product_image'];
        $pro_qty = $row['product_qty'];
        $pro_fullprice = $row['product_fullprice'];

        $checkforqty = "select product_qty from products";
        $runcheck = mysqli_query($con, $checkforqty);

            $i = 1;

            if($pro_qty == 0){
                $list .= "<div id='single_product' >

                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
                </br>
                <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪ :מחיר</p>
                <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
                </br>
                <a href='#'><button class='button_addCart' style='background-color:gray;'>הוסף לסל</button></a>
                <p style='font-size:10px; color:red;'>מוצר זה אזל במלאי</p>
            </div>";
            } else {
                $list .=  "<div id='single_product'>
                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
                </br>
                <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪ :מחיר</p>
                <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
                </br>
                <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button class='button_addCart'>הוסף לסל</button></a>
                <form name='f1' method='post'>
                <input type='button' name='inc' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"$i++\").value++;' value='+' />
                <input type='text' size='1' name='quan' id='$i++' value='1' />
                <input type='button' name='dec' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"$i++\").value--;' value='-' /> 

                </form>

            </div>";


            }


}
```

edited the code, my final intention is to give unique id to the form at the bottom of the loop so the JS could differ between the forms

Comment: Why don't you have [php open and close tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)?

Comment: I have its just the part of the code where I need help with, the whole loop is 40 lines of code

Comment: @Svidlak if you post the whole loop, then we'd we able to see how it works, and not just the bit you are showing, which brought the comment of the open/close tags.  It doesn't matter if it's 40 lines, it's certainly relevant to the question in order to avoid confusion

Comment: @OIS edited with the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code outputs the value of $i then increases it. So inc and dec does not use the id which is used by quan.

Generate your id first, then use it for all 3 elements.

```
<?php
$id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
echo <<< EOMF
<form name='f1' method='post'>
    <input type='button' name='inc' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById("$id").value++;' value='+' />
    <input type='text' size='1' name='quan' id='$ic' value='1' />
    <input type='button' name='dec' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById("$id").value--;' value='-' /> 
</form>
EOMF;
```

or with your code

```
$id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
$list .= <<< EOMF
<div id='single_product'>
    <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
    </br>
    <h3>$pro_title</h3>
    <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪ :מחיר</p>
    <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
    </br>
    <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button class='button_addCart'>הוסף לסל</button></a>
    <form name='f1' method='post'>
        <input type='button' name='inc' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById("$id").value++;' value='+' />
        <input type='text' size='1' name='quan' id='$id' value='1' />
        <input type='button' name='dec' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById("$id").value--;' value='-' /> 
    </form>
</div>
EOMF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    <?php

    $i=0;

    while($i<10){

    echo '<input type="text" id="'.$i.'">';

    $i++;  
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$i = 1;

```
            if($pro_qty == 0){
                $list .= "<div id='single_product' >

                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
                </br>
                <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪ :מחיר</p>
                <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
                </br>
                <a href='#'><button class='button_addCart' style='background-color:gray;'>הוסף לסל</button></a>
                <p style='font-size:10px; color:red;'>מוצר זה אזל במלאי</p>
            </div>";
            } else {
                $list .=  "<div id='single_product'>
                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
                </br>
                <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪ :מחיר</p>
                <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
                </br>
                <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button class='button_addCart'>הוסף לסל</button></a>
                <form name='f1' method='post'>
                <input type='button' name='inc' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"$i++\").value++;' value='+' />
                <input type='text' size='1' name='quan' id='."$i++."' value='1' />
                <input type='button' name='dec' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"$i++\").value--;' value='-' /> 

                </form>

            </div>";

                    </form>

                </div>";


                }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You update your form from

`<form name='f1' method='post'>`

To

`<form name='f1' id='".$pro_id."' method='post'>`

Your each form will have a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution

make a function:

```
function change_value(operation, id){
     if(operation)
     document.getElementById(id).value++;
     else
     document.getElementById(id).value--;
}
```

then:

```
$list.= "<input type='button' name='inc' onclick='change_value(true,".$i.");' value='+' />
<input type='text' size='1' name='quan' id='".$i."' value='1' />
<input type='button' name='dec' onclick='change_value(false,".$i.");' value='-' />";

$i++;
```